# Goto top when clicked on a Anchor Tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a video player with a grid of video thumbnails when i click  the thumbnail its video will be played on the player but it does not scrolls automatically to the top of the page

I found the script which made it to move to the top when it clicked .

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[href=#top]').click(function() {
        $('#top').animate({scrollTop: 0},600);
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
<body> 
<a href="#top">asdf</a>
</body>
```

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: I already have a anchor tag for each thumbnail how can i include the #top to my existing anchor tag

Answer (score 4):

```
$("a[href='#top']").click(function() {
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
  return false;
});
```

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fRUUd/1440/)

Answer (score 1):

the mistake is in your animate element selection it should be like this:

```
$(this).animate({scrollTop: 0},600);
```

the selector #top would search for an element with the ID of top

Answer (score 0):

Your animate element selection should be like this:

```
$(this).animate({scrollTop: 0},600);
```